# How to physically partitions model view controller ( MVC ) in Zend Framework?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, partitioning, saas

I am developing a SaaS based product in Zend Framework. The system should be scalable to distrubute the load on the application server. So I want to separate physically Model-View-Controller (MVC) on the different server rather than keeping on the same application server. So that they should communicate with each other through web service.

I am new to Zend Framework and what to know that Does it possible in Zend Framework to physically partitions of MVC on different server? How to achieve it? An example will help me to boost my confidence level.

Your response would be help me lots.

I am thanking all of you in advance!

Comment: Is this some kind of joke or something? What protocol do you think you would use to *transfer* the data between different machines?

Comment: If you want to make different sections and not want to clutter the code you can use concept of modules, you can do certain optimization like using opcode cache and CDN, but distributing code files is not a solution

Comment: Model-View-Controller are all parts of the 'application', so they should all live on the application server.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? Have you done any benchmark? How much time does this take to you to implement safely such system compared to the performance gain?

If you want your website to be scalable, don't make **any** pre-optimization, premature optimization are **evil**, really.

Build you application, profile it, find the bottleneck, and optimize at a later time.

A scalable application is first an application which can evolves easily meaning well designed architecture.

You better use a load-balancer with several frontend and use a shared cache between frontend instances, like memcached, Redis.

Comment: Are you sure that this applies to OPs question ?

Comment: @tereško, sure, obviously it is not an how-to-like answer, but better that bindly tell the OP the "way to do" I think it is more valuable in this case to tell him, why he shouldn't, and how to solve his "performance problematic" with a more bullet-proof solution.

Comment: @tereško, Thanks for your answer. I understand that my question is more towards to optimization of the application. I can apply caching mechanism for optimization and add load balance to distribute load among several application servers for Scalability. I just wanted to know that is there any way to separate MVC on different application server.